# return another MVC3 view of the same controller after ajax is used

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

How to return another view of the same controller? I made some debugging  for the application: the ajax method calls the controller action, pass the parameter, executes the instructions. At the

```
return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);,
```

the "`GetEmployeeDays`" view receives the values from model and is populated, but finally in the browser I receive the initial view (from I made the request) - not the `GetEmployeeDays` view

routing code from Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );          
  }
```

JQuery code that calls the action controller's and pass a parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('li').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { userCode: $(this).attr('id') }
   })
  });
});
```

Controller action that should render the `GetEmployeeDays` view:

```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult GetEmployeeDays(string userCode)
   {
      .....
    return View("GetEmployeeDays", model);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply load something to a part of your page without reloading to a new page, you should update the specific part of your page in the callback of your ajax function.

```
$(function(){
 $('li').click(function () {
     var uCode=$(this).attr("id");
     $.get("@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays","ApproveWork")?userCode="+uCode,
                                                          function(response){
       $("#DivToBeUpdated").html(response);
     });
 });
});
```

If you want to redirect to a new view, you should do it by updating the `location.href` property value.

```
$(function(){
 $('li').click(function () {
     var uCode=$(this).attr("id");
     var url="@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays","ApproveWork")?userCode="+uCode;
     window.location.href=url;         
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you; i need to return a new view.

Comment: Thanks again; It appears an syntax error near `"GetEmployeeDays"` and indicates me to put an `;`. I try to see why.

Comment: I solved to : `var url='@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays","ApproveWork")?userCode='+uCode;`.

Comment: @pisi: Glad you made it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect via ajax request. Try a simple GET request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').on('click', function()
{
   document.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork")' + '?param1=val1&param2=val2';
});
</script>
```

The controller is fine as it is now.

**EDITED:** Updated as requested

Comment: Thank you for your help @David Diez! this method works, but it I need to pass a parameter, that's why I used ajax function

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your original view is that is being re-rendered, I'd say that most likely your issue is that you should be returning this as a PartialView, since you are making an Ajax request.  In addition, it doesn't look like you are actually rendering the result anywhere.  What is your fiddler response?  Does it show returned HTML?  If it does, you probably just need to dump it onto the page by utilizing the .done callback within $.ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('li').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork")',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { userCode: $(this).attr('id') }
    }).done(function() {
       $(this).addClass("done");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: David is correct in that View() will cause your layout to be re-rendered, returning anything in your "master page" and possibly junking up your view and your script. Using a partial response instead will prevent that from happening.  +1 on the Fiddler suggestion as well.

Comment: @MisterJames and David L Thanks for support. I used in a first time PartialView; that was rendered ok, but on the BACK browser action  the page was blanck, that's why I tried to use a normal view

Comment: Using normal views are fine if you aren't interested in AJAXifying your calls.  In that case, you can use HTML.ActionLink calls to reference a new page, rather than using Ajax to load content dynamically into your current page.  However, if are using Ajax, you will want to return partial content and place it in your page.

Comment: So I can't return a new view with dynamically content, that depends on  another page events ?

Answer (score 0):

?Building from @David Diez, you can append parameters to your request as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').on('click', function()
{
   document.location.href = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork", new { caseSensativeParamName = "foo" })';
});
</script>
```

You can, of course, go a JavaScript route as well. Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('li').on('click', function()
{
   var targetUrl = '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDays", "ApproveWork")';
   var yourParam = $("#input-id").val();
   targetUrl = targetUrl + '?yourServerParamName=' + yourParam;
   document.location.href = targetUrl;
});
</script>
```

Cheers.